# Ошибка при отправление вложения VK_API на Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь сделать эхо-бота, который будет отправлять в ответ картинку из пересланного сообщения, но выскакивает vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid

Все правильно и должно работать, но.... (?)

P.S. добавил в код print, чтобы повторно проверить правильность вложения, и все верно. Выводит что-то, например, такое: photo519842539_457239417_4805938e2a696f1d8f

```
for event in longpoll.listen(): 
    print(event)
    id = event.object.reply_message["attachments"][0]["photo"]["id"]
    owner_id = event.object.reply_message["attachments"][0]["photo"]["owner_id"]
    acces_key = event.object.reply_message["attachments"][0]["photo"]["access_key"]
    photo = "photo" + str(owner_id) + "_" + str(id) + "_" + acces_key
    print(photo)
    vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.object.peer_id, random_id = get_random_id(), attachment = photo)
```

Comment: Попробуйте в `vk.messages.send` добавить параметр `message = ' '`

Comment: не, не работает, та же ошибка

Comment: Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой, вы не нашли решения ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не знаю, можно ли это назвать ответом на вопрос, или нет. Скорее нет, но другого решения, полагаю, здесь не дадут, а обратиться больше и некуда.

В общем, тот access_key, который даётся при использовании vk_api, по какой-то непонятной причине отличается от того, который на самом деле содержится в фото (можно просто скопировать ссылку и посмотреть там). В итоге, если мы возьмём access_key из скопированной ссылки на фото, вставим его в код, то все заработает.

Вероятно, я что-то делаю не так, но если есть решения того, как все это по-другому можно сделать — напишите, пожалуйста, сюда.